# Display Image to Browser Directly from PC source using javascript

Tags: javascript

i would like to display an image in a browser, when user clicks on a button they can search for pictures from computer and display that picture to browser.
how can i do that?
thanks a lot for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preview an image before it is uploaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for browser images in local computer forget it. You can't do it on client side.

Comment: You can't do it directly with Javascript then. You need to use PHP, ASP or similar through a HTML form. Use a <input type='file'> to browse the files